# how to get slave lag using sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

is there a way to get the current slave lag using sql alchemy? session.execute('show slave status') appears to return no rows:

```
In [0]: list(session.execute('show slave status'))

ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@your.hostname.com/')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("SHOW SLAVE STATUS") 
for row in result:
   for k in row.keys():
     print k, ' >>> ', row[k]
```